# How to do a three-way frequency table in R?

Tags: r, frequency, crosstab

I'm trying to code a three-way frequency table in **R**, but I'm stumbling due the number of variables I have. I have 4 columns of variables, Depression (Yes, No, NA- I need to keep NAs), Under(yes, no, NA), Normal(yes, no, NA), and Obese(yes, no, NA). I want the table to look something like this?

```
                      Depression
                 Yes     No     NA
Weight      
Under            70      20     5


Normal           90      68     8


Obese            40      20     6
```

I've tried doing cross tab but it would give me a table where cancer is included as one of the cities :( I really thank for any help in advanced!

Btw, I've tried tabular from tables package but it gave me an error when I was producing a markdown

Comment: You may need `ftable` i.e. `ftable(df1[c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")])`

Comment: It looks like your output is not really a three-way table, but actually a two-way table composed of _derived_ variables. You need to create the `Weight` and `Depression` columns yourself, then you can simply run `table` on those two. You might create `Weight` as `c('Under', 'Normal', 'Obese')[Under + 2*Normal + 3*Obses]`

Comment: @akrun That gives me something different.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two-way table problem. As others might end up here, too, here is a simple solution for a three-way table:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% select('x','y','z') %>% ftable()
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular `table` function can do it. Consider:

```
# Mock data:
n <- 100
mys <- function(x) sample(x, size = n, replace = TRUE)
A <- mys(letters[1:3])
B <- mys(LETTERS[1:4])
C <- mys(paste(1:5))

# Three way table:
table(A,B,C,  useNA = "always")
#, , C = 1
#
#      B
#A      A B C D <NA>
#  a    0 2 0 1    0
#  b    2 1 0 0    0
#  c    3 0 2 2    0
#  <NA> 0 0 0 0    0
#
#, , C = 2
#
 #     B
#A      A B C D <NA>
#  a    2 1 2 2    0
#  b    2 4 0 1    0
#  c    0 5 5 3    0
#  <NA> 0 0 0 0    0
#
# . . .
```

The argument `useNA` can then be set as you need. See `?table`. After that, you can subset/slice the 3-way table as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is not a three-way table, but rather a two-way table with 3 categories per variable. I hope this code is useful:

```
matrix1 <- matrix(c(70, 20, 5, 90, 68, 8, 40, 20, 6))

tab <- as.table(matrix(matrix1, nrow = 3, byrow = T, 
                           dimnames = list(Weight = c('Under','Normal','Obese'), 
                                           Depression = c('Yes', 'No', 'NA'))))

tab

         Depression
 Weight   Yes No NA
 Under   70 20  5
 Normal  90 68  8
 Obese   40 20  6
```